# ArcGIS Pro Package Manager Busted

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm on Windows 10 and I can't seem to update or add any packages. When I try through the Package Manager GUI it spins for awhile and then has the failed icon in the Tasks box.

The output is always:"Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... "

I've cloned the environment, multiple times, tried running as admin, and even using conda from command line it always gets hung at this same spot. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: It's your installation a university install, if so you might need to talk to your it department?

Comment: Thanks, this is personal use though

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a corrupted condarc file.  Mine is located here:  C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134985/conda-install-packages-error-collecting-package-metadata-current-repodata-json) for more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It actually never even says "failed", like in the instance of the above issue. Gets hung up on working.... 

I've deleted a lot of folders and reinstalled ArcGIS Pro. I can't even update metadata for my installed packages.